# Creating "Scrollable" Output in Command Line Programs

Tags: python

I have a program that outputs anywhere from 300-1000 lines of data. Rather than have it all output at once, I'd like it to have a manpages-like interface where it will display the first 50 or so lines of input and then the user can press 'f' or 'b' to navigate through the pages. Is there a way to do this in Python?

Note: I want to distribute the program, and I don't want to force users to pipe the output to less/more. Moreover, the output occurs in the middle of the program and is not the only output of the program, so I'm not sure if that would work any way.

Comment: you can always pipe it through `less` or `more`

Comment: Why not use a simple `less` command in bash? From your question, it seems you are using the command line anyway

Comment: Yes, but I want to distribute the program and make it as user friendly as possible. Sure, anyone who's using a command line program in the first place likely knows about `less` or `more`, but it's still nice to have that output formatted for you. Besides, the output isn't necessarily the end of the program. The user will have more options once the text is output.

Comment: edited original to reflect this

Comment: @user1427661 In that case this I'm not sure this question is of an appropriate scope for SO. (Unless searching "python pager library" returns something that's done already. Which it seems to so you might want to investigate that.)

Comment: How is a question about code to format output not appropriate scope for SO? If it's not, I'll move it to the appropriate place, but just wondering.

Comment: @user1427661 SO is for questions of the form "I tried doing X and hit problem Y, how to resolve this problem?" Generally, questions of the form "I have a user requirement X, how do I do it all?" are considered "too broad". (You might, or might not get pointers via comments or whatever, but they can't be considered as high quality answers which is why the question isn't really kept for posterity.) It doesn't help that a bunch of searches would've moved you forward. (Not necessarily obvious searches, but SO is also not here to teach people to Google better / explain terminology.)

Comment: Searching for "python console ui library" also gave me [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) which might handle even some concerns you haven't mentioned..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something very rudimentary like:

```
# pseudocode 
def display_text(text):
    lines = text.splitlines()
    while lines remaining:
        display next N lines
        wait for key press
```

To "wait for key press", you could do something like this: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/123777/press-any-key-to-continue

Answer (score 2):

Note: I would never do this, and I think it is very bad UIX, but ...

```
pager = subprocess.Popen(['less'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then write all of your command's output to the file-like object: `pager.stdin`